# hollywood script pdf output error at pdftex.map

Tags: undefined

MacTeX just installed, added `hollywood.cls`.

Even a simple test file created with `hollywood`-template fails at

```
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]

! Undefined control sequence. l.16 \fadein{}

The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed.
```

A series of errors follow, all unrecognized `hollywood` paragraph formats. What am I missing?

Comment: how do you edit your document?

Comment: Your question is missing quite some information. E.g. where you got hollywood.cls from, and how the template looks like.

Comment: Do you mean TeX Live Utility? MacTeX installs a full version of TeX Live As released this past June. I suggest you send a bug report to the maintainer of the Hollywood class.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Found an alternative hollywood.cls. Significantly larger. After installing the new cls file in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base (again, this is Mac OSX) I only had one unrecognized command, "\description." I added that by editing the cls file with vi. Copied the block defining "\narrative" and changed "narrative" to "description." Worked fine. To be thorough I should look for the difference between these two layouts, but I am satisfied. Also, I think the cls file belongs in a different location, outside the base.